# why does my usercontrol keep resetting it's visible property to false?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok, I have a usercontrol on my page.

On the page, the visible property is set to false.

On the OnPreRender event, I set the visible property to true.

It runs the line of code, but does not actually change anything. (so visible remains at false)

This exact same method works across every other control, and there is nothing special about this control.

Any ideas??

Comment: Post the code.  What you're saying sounds impossible on the face of it so we need to see the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check for the visible property on any controls containing this control.

Setting Visible=True does not mean that Visible==True, it will still return False if a parent control is False.

Other than that though, you may need to post some examples of your code in order for anyone to help track down what the problem may be.

Comment: What an idiot I am. I did know that, but forgot to check.

Thanks very much - this has sorted it. (the parent control was the bit hiding it, as suggested)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and... yes the problem is the parents not be visible. So I made this little peace of code to solve the problem:

```
  public static void ForceVisibleState(Control control, bool visible)
  {
     if (!visible)
     {
        control.Visible = false;
     }
     else
     {
        // Must set all parents to 'visible = true'
        List<Control> parents = new List<Control>();
        while (control != null &&
               !control.Visible)
        {
           parents.Insert(0, control);
           control = control.Parent;
        }
        foreach(Control parent in parents)
        {
           parent.Visible = true;
        } 
     }
  }
```